# Applying custom styles to Android SpinnerItems

Tags: android, android-layout

This question has been asked before, but carefully studying the answers on previous posts hasn't helped me decipher the problem.

I'm trying to apply custom styles to the items in a spinner control in my Android app, using a custom theme. I can't get the spinner items to respect the custom styles.

Here's what I have in `themes.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/CustomSpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">25dp</item> <!-- This works -->
  </style>
</resources>
```

And here's my `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>  
  <style name="CustomSpinnerItem" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTextAppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dp</item> <!-- This works fine -->
  </style>

  <style name="CustomTextAppearanceSpinnerItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item> <!-- This does NOT work -->
  </style>
</resources>
```

Note the comments about what's working and what isn't. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the `CustomTextAppearanceSpinnerItem` section, but I'm at a loss as to what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter for your spinner?

Comment: Hah, no, but I had set a custom layout in the `ArrayAdapter` that I'd forgotten about. Thanks!

Comment: I was going to say, you could just set your styles on a custom layout that you use for the spinner items.

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MySpinnerItem" parent="@android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MySpinnerTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="MySpinnerTextAppearance" parent="@android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
</resources>
```